# Custom cell is blank when inserted into TableView. Not blank when the app is closed and reopened

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am new to iOS development and I am creating my first app, so sorry if the question is really bad. I am using the Master/Detail template in Xcode and using Core Data. I changed the template to use a custom cell style in the tableView. When the user wants to add something they are switched over to another view to complete a form. When the user clicks Save the form data is saved to Core Data and then the view segues back to the MasterView.

My problem is that when the form is saved the tableView updates to show the new cell but it is blank intermittently [tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISCfP.png). Sometimes this will happen, other times it won't happen. The cell stay blank until the app is closed from the app switcher and reopened.

Is there anything I'm forgetting to change? Thanks for the help.

Here are the functions I changed in the template to add my custom cell style:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
    self.configureCell(cell, withObject: object)
    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: CustomTableViewCell, withObject object: NSManagedObject) {

    let imageData: NSData = object.valueForKey("image") as! NSData
    let picture: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
    let date: NSDate
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()


    cell.cellImage.image = picture
    cell.locationNameLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("name")!.description
    cell.categoryLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("category")!.description

    date = object.valueForKey("date")! as! NSDate

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    cell.dateLabel!.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)


}
```

This is the only function that I changed for the FetchedResultsController

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
        self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)! as! CustomTableViewCell, withObject: anObject as! NSManagedObject)
    case .Move:
        tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to reload the data after you have added the cell and when you are segue back to the table view. You can use `self.tableView.reloadData()` to reload your entire table or `self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)`to reload a specific cell.
I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried using `tableView.reloadData()` and the issue is still there. I've also placed reload functions in the viewWillAppear and also the viewDidLoad methods and they didn't help either.

Comment: And you said when you close the app and reopen it, the app pulls in the correct data that you had entered in the form before and enters it into the cell correctly?

Comment: Yes, when I close the app the information appears in the cell. The strange thing is that if i don't close the app, I can still click on the blank cell like in the picture I posted above and it will take me to the correct detail view with the information in it. For some reason it just doesn't want to display the custom cell until I close and reopen.

Comment: Yeah, if you follow through this tutorial, it explains adding core data items to a table: http://www.learncoredata.com/create-retrieve-update-delete-data-with-core-data/

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully one of these two tutorials will be able to help you:
http://www.learncoredata.com/create-retrieve-update-delete-data-with-core-data/
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-nsfetchedresultscontroller--cms-25072